# Minecraft forge 1.7.10 server keeps crashing on a mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge, minecraft-pixelmon

Does anyone know why when i click on the forge 1.7.10 server jar file on a mac it crashes. I am trying to start up a minecraft pixelmelon server on mac that runs on 1.7.10 but i am not able to do so cause this happens.

Comment: do you have any crash logs or any more details that you can give us

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft tech support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file "eula.txt" and set the parameter "=false" to "=true" then save the eula.txt.